# AWS: Is it possible to connect ALB with NLB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-nlb

Trying to configure my AWS K8s cluster (EKS).

Currently I am using this schema:

```
Internet -> NLB -> Nginx ingress -> Pod
```

Now I have requirement to use AWS WAF service. As WAF can`t work with NLB, looks like I have only two options:

1. Start to use ALB instead NLB:

   `Internet -> ALB (instead NLB) -> Nginx ingress -> Pod`
2. Add ALB in my chain:

   `Internet -> ALB (+WAF) -> NLB -> Nginx ingress -> Pod`

So, my question is - what option is better?
Is it possible to point ALB to NLB? In this case I need minimum (I guess) changes in my current structure. Or, it is better to switch from NLB to ALB?

Comment: Even if it is possible to redirect ALB to NLB, `Internet -> ALB (instead NLB) -> Nginx ingress -> Pod` seems more correct

Comment: more correct and more cost effective while serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/) to route traffic directly to your pods. If you need to use nginx, you can configure your environment like this Internet -> NLB -> ALB -> nginx ingress. ALB can be a target for the NLB. This blog explains how to configure it, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/application-load-balancer-type-target-group-for-network-load-balancer/. You'll need to configure the NLB outside of the AWS Load Balancer controller/Kubernetes because the controller doesn't recognize ALB as a target type.